# Let $Z \sim Z(0, 1)$ be a standard normal random variable. Find the PDF of $|Z|$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification

> Let $Z \sim Z(0, 1)$ be a standard normal random variable. Find
>   the PDF of $|Z|$.

**My approach:**

I let $Y = |Z|$, found the CDF and then took the first derivative to get the PDF.

For $0 \leq y \leq 1$, the CDF is given by:

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y)$$
$$= P(-y \leq Z \leq y)$$
$$= F_Z(y) - F_Z(-y) \tag{$*$}$$

Hence the PDF is given by,

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}(F_Y(y))$$
$$= \frac{d}{dy}(F_Z(y) - F_Z(-y)) \; \text{by }(*)$$
$$= \frac{d}{dy}(F_Z(y)) - (\frac{d}{dy}F_Z(-y))$$
$$=1\cdot f_Z(y)-(-1\cdot f_Z(-y))$$
$$=f_Z(y)+f_Z(-y))$$

The PDF of a standard normal distribution is given by $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^\frac{-x^2}{2}$ so we have,
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^\frac{-y^2}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^\frac{y^2}{2}$$

I am not too sure if this is the correct answer and approach to this question so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Minus sign glitch, it should be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}$ (for $y\gt 0$). Note that your answer cannot be right, its integral blows up.

Comment: If $Y=|Z|$ then $f_Y(y)=f_Z(y)+f_Z(-y)$ for $y \gt 0$ and so if $f_Z(z)=f_Z(-z)$ then, as you almost end up with, $f_Y(y)=2f_Z(y)$ for $y \gt 0$

Comment: Standard notation is $Z\sim Z(0,1)$ (or $Z\sim N(0,1)$), not $Z\text{~}Z(0,1)$. I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This is often known as the [folded normal distriution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had the right answer, but you need to be careful when evaluating $f_Z(-y)$.

Since $(-y)^2 = y^2$, we have $f_Z(-y) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\dfrac{(-y)^2}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\dfrac{y^2}{2}}$.

Thus, your final answer ends up being $f_Y(y) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\dfrac{y^2}{2}}$ for $y \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you! didn't catch that =p